# "What we want is for the amendment to be withdrawn" vs. ""What we want is the amendment to be withdrawn"

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between:

> What we want is the amendment to be withdrawn.

and:

> What we want is **for** the amendment to be withdrawn.

? If so, what does the *for* express in the second statement then?

Comment: I do not notice any differences in meaning between these sentences except for word count.

Comment: @katahtahito so both are grammatical?